# Bilinear Functions on $R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If **B** is a bilinear function on $R^n$x $R^m$ with real values show that $DB_{(P,Q)}$(h,k)=B(P,k)+B(h,Q)

Not sure where to even start, something where the limit of B(h,k)/||(h,k)|| should go to 0 as (h,k) goes to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m)$ are coordinates in some basis, then there are constants $a_{ij}$ such that
$$B(x,y)=\sum_{i,j}{a_{ij}x_iy_j}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{B(p+h,q+k)-B(p,q)-DB_{(p,q)}(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}\\=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{B(p,q)+B(h,q)+B(p,k)+B(h,k)-B(p,q)-DB_{(p,q)}(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}\\=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{B(h,q)+B(p,k)+B(h,k)-DB_{(p,q)}(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|} \\=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{B(h,q)+B(p,k)+B(h,k)-B(h,q)-B(p,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}\\=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{B(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{B(h,0)+B(0,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}=0.$$